# Having trouble transferring file to a new folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, files

I get this message when I try moving a file to a new folder

```
sudo mv bios.rom usr/share/higan/GameBoyAdvance.sys
mv: cannot move 'bios.rom' to 'usr/share/higan/GameBoyAdvance.sys': no such file or directory
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu; I'm learning. Is there a way I can change this folder to be a directory or should I just reinstall the app? The app is Higan V94 64 x 64, Nintendo emulator. I'm trying to place the GameBoy Advance Bios in the right folder but I can't. I have even tried `sudo mv bios.rom usr/share/higan/Game Boy Advance.sys`

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Answer (score 3):

Check that the file `bios.rom` is actually in the current working directory `~/Desktop` by typing `ls`.

If you can see the file `bios.rom`, you just need to put a `/` at the start of the path to `mv` to

```
sudo mv bios.rom /usr/share/higan/GameBoyAdvance.sys
```

if the directory name has spaces in it like `Game Boy Advance.sys`, you need to use the `\` character to escape them like this:

```
sudo mv bios.rom /usr/share/higan/Game\ Boy\ Advance.sys
```

Otherwise `mv` will get confused...

If the file `bios.rom` is **not** in the current working directory, then you have to `cd` to the directory where it is first, or use the absolute path, for example, if it's in your `~/Downloads` directory:

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/bios.rom /usr/share/higan/Game\ Boy\ Advance.sys
```

---

**Explanation of the error**

The path `usr/share...` does not exist under `~/Desktop`, which is the current working directory. `usr` is under `/`, the root directory. If you type `ls` where you are now, you can see no `usr`, but type `cd /` and then `ls` you will see it there, under `/`